# Apache serving wrong VirtualHost

Tags: server, apache2

Okay, this is my first question so bear with me!

I host a website for myself and the local high school alumni.

I want to set up on https://dev.coolcomputers.info client certificate authentication the only problem is it sometimes gives the Handshake failure (like i want) and sometimes it loads the main site https://www.coolcomputers.info.

If you need more info please feel free to ask!

apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-07-27T14:34:01

Included is my config for both Sites

**Main Site:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SuexecUserGroup "#1001" "#1001"
ServerName www.coolcomputers.info
ServerAlias coolcomputers.info autoconfig.coolcomputers.info autodiscover.coolcomputers.info
DocumentRoot /home/coolcomputers/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/coolcomputers.info_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/coolcomputers.info_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/coolcomputers/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/coolcomputers/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /AutoDiscover/AutoDiscover.xml /home/coolcomputers/cgi-bin/autoconfig.cgi
ScriptAlias /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml /home/coolcomputers/cgi-bin/autoconfig.cgi
ScriptAlias /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml /home/coolcomputers/cgi-bin/autoconfig.cgi
<Directory /home/coolcomputers/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php7.0 .php7.0
</Directory>
<Directory /home/coolcomputers/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/coolcomputers/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/coolcomputers/privkey.pem
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "coolcomputers.info statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/coolcomputers/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
Redirect /mail/config-v1.1.xml "/cgi-bin/autoconfig.cgi"
Redirect /.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml "/cgi-bin/autoconfig.cgi"
ServerAdmin postmaster@coolcomputers.info
SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCACertificateFile /home/coolcomputers/ssl.ca
</VirtualHost>
```

**Dev Site**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/test"
ServerName dev.coolcomputers.info
ServerAdmin postmaster@coolcomputers.info
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.dev.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.dev.log "combined"
LogLevel debug
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/dev/dev.coolcomputers.info.cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/dev/dev.coolcomputers.info.key.pem
SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/dev/ca.cert.pem
SSLCARevocationFile /etc/ssl/dev/intermediate.crl.pem
SSLCARevocationCheck leaf
<Directory /var/test>
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 5
SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "CoolComputers Inc." \
       and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Secure Intermediate Authority"}
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Last but not least related output of "apache2ctl -S"

```
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server dev.coolcomputers.info (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-dev.coolcomputers.info.conf:1)
         port 443 namevhost dev.coolcomputers.info (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-dev.coolcomputers.info.conf:1)
         port 443 namevhost mail.coolcomputers.info (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-mail.coolcomputers.info.conf:1)
         port 443 namevhost www.coolcomputers.info (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/coolcomputers.info.conf:35)
                 alias coolcomputers.info
                 alias autoconfig.coolcomputers.info
                 alias autodiscover.coolcomputers.info
         port 443 namevhost pshalumni.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/pshalumni.org.conf:46)
                 alias www.pshalumni.org
                 alias autoconfig.pshalumni.org
                 alias autodiscover.pshalumni.org
```

Comment: Have cleared the cache?

Comment: Just tried that does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 5

Can not be placed inside the Directory stanza when using Document Root