# Apache 2.4 randomly return wrong certificate

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, certificates, apache2.4

I've a server with ~50 different Virtual Hosts, ~10 with SSL enabled. Everything worked perfectly until last week, when I added another host with SSL, it is configured exactly like the other hosts, with the same *brand* of certificate, and Apache is randomly returning wrong certificate only for this host.

The strangest thing is that 50% of the time it returns the correct certificate, and the other 50% of the time it returns a wrong certificate, from another of the sites.

This is the .conf file of the new host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      subdomain.new_site.com
        Redirect    /   https://subdomain.new_site.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName      subdomain.new_site.com

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /var/ca/new_site/ServerCertificate.cer
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ca/new_site/private.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /var/ca/new_site/CACertificate.cer

        DocumentRoot /var/www/new_site
</VirtualHost>
```

My server is running Ubuntu Server 16.04.6 LTS with updated Apache from repositories:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-04-03T13:34:47
```

`apachectl -t` returns `Syntax OK`

Comment: according to [Apache documentations](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) the `SSLCertificateChainFile` directive is deprecated. So I would start looking from there. I see you have many certificate files and I have not used commercial certificate so I'm not sure what the instruction is but it might be helpful to go through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370454/sslcertificatechainfile-is-obsolete).

Comment: are you certain it's not something cached in your browser? is there a difference if you add/remove www? do you have any .htaccess files?

Comment: Maybe the dns pointing to `new_site.com` are not fully propagated and each time You dns is being queried it is actually different dns server responding...

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz that's why I'm wondering if adding a www. at the beginning of the url will change things... also, shouldn't there also be something in the conf to identify the url www.new_site.com?

Comment: It is possible for `new_site.com` and `www.new_site.com` to point to different ip. Try to add www and see if that helps. You can always query dns itself by `dig new_site.com` or `dig www.new_site.com`.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz and joshua-besneatte it's a subdomain, so that's not the problem. I updated the question.

Comment: @TonyCeralva have you checked to see which cert is actually being served?  Without seeing what cert(s) are being served it could be a problem.  Is this an internal CA certificate as well or a commercial certificate you obtained from, say, GoDaddy or some other trusted certificate provider?

Comment: I would still think this is some issue with FQDN/DNS...

Comment: Have you read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954437/apache-serving-wrong-virtualhost?rq=1) link ?